# How to select a OnetoOne field from a QuerySet in a view?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

See all users (that don't have search_hidden enabled) view

```
@login_required
def users(request):
    """List all users page"""
    t_users = User.objects.all()
    users = t_users.usersettings.filter(search_hidden=False).select_related('user')

    context = {'users': users}
    return render(request, 'users/users.html', context)
```

UserSettings model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class UserSettings(models.Model):
    """Stores the user's settings."""

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='usersettings', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    public_profile = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    search_hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'usersettings'

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s settings"

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_usersettings(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserSettings.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_usersettings(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.usersettings.save()
```

All users have a UserSettings model tied to them when their accounts are created. In my view, I want to select all users that have search_hidden disabled, however what I've tried doesn't work.The error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'usersettings'` is displayed whenever the page is requested. I probably need to select each user and retrieve the settings, but I don't know how to do that in an efficient manner.

Comment: since the ```QuerySet``` does not have ```usersettings``` method. What is this ```usersettings``` ?

Comment: a model tied to the user model through a OnetoOneField. The error occurs because the queryset object isn't related to that model, but rather the contents (the individual users)

Comment: here ```QuerySet``` is the main object you can not call ```usersettings```. do this ```t_users.objects.filter(search_hidden=True/False)```

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you could post that as an answer, as it gives you reputation and closes the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iliya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867239/iliya) commented that filtering using `t_users.objects.filter(search_hidden=False)` would return users where *search_hidden* is not true in their settings object.